# Error 500 on new sub-domain

Tags: php, htaccess, webserver, error, error-code

I have just uploaded a site on a sub-domain, In fact on the 3rd Sub-domain. All the 4 site ( 1 Main, and the 3 on SUB) are completely separate from each other.

Now, the site was developed Offline/Local and then uploaded, the site worked great on a local.

For some reason i keep getting "ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR", where as my other sites are working fine.

If it would have been a server issue, the other sites would have the same problem. I dont ahve limits on Sub-domains, the disk space and bandwidth is also fine.

Can't Understand what could be the issue. Please help. I have attached the screen shot to the post, but not the link. As i am not sure how it works here.

.Htaccess code :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?$1=$1 [QSA,L]
 #RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
 #RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
 #RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zcA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php?id=$3 [L]

 php_value max_execution_time 200
 php_value post_max_size 200M
 php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
```

[image: Error 500]

[image: info.php]

Comment: what technology you using for site? PHP / wordpress?

Comment: It's on PHP....

Comment: can you please share .htaccess file code which are in that sub domain root folder?

Comment: I'm sorry, how do i post the code here? It's all scrambled. I'm new here.

Comment: please update question and add . htaccess code in proper format there. In comment not possible to format proper.

Comment: @helpinghands, like this ?

Comment: its ok I have formatted code proper in question. Let me take a look in detail now.

Comment: @HelpingHands can you also let me know how to place the code properly on the Question it self. Please.

Comment: For that you need to write code between {  }.

Comment: Do you using ? <IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>
 in .htaccess.?

Comment: No, i have not used that in my .htaccess file. @HelpingHands

Comment: I have added answer , please check and follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to : [Default htaccess](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) and use that default htaccess code for .htaccess file for your subdomain root.

Also please verify following things :

1 - In apache config , see this option  : AllowOverride All [It should be ALL not none]

2 - do you have mod_rewrite enabled

3 - .Htaccess file permission should be 644.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the code in .htaccss, and the file permission is set to 644.

But, no idea how to check for mod_rewrite and apache config

Comment: Please create new page and use function                                 <?php

phpinfo();

?    and then access that page. it will show you all status.

Comment: what exactly goes in the code? 

"<?php phpinfo(); ?" this? within the quotes?

Comment: It will give you all php info. all option status of server which are on , which are off and a lot more.

Comment: yes, but how to use it?

Comment: As I said , just create new page in your site. for example : info.php and then in that file put function "<?php phpinfo(); ?> and then access file via browser like yoursite.com/info.php

Comment: Ok, i'm getting the same error. 
ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: will if it help if i share the URL?

Comment: no first you have to see php info page , in that does "mod_rewrite" = on?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess - Check here you will get ready made htaccess code for sub domain.

Comment: please see the image attached (updated), this is what i am getting.

Comment: Did you try .htaccess code from here ?  
codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: Ok, I just tried the same with my main site and the other 2 subdomains, and it works, showing all details. 

But, it dosnt on this sub-domain

Comment: you please take copy of .htaccess file from any subdomain which are working then paste that file to root of 3rd subdomain which is not working.

Comment: Dude! you are genius. It worked!! I used the .htaccess codes from the link that you gave me. 

Thanks a lot Mate!

Answer (score 0):

Start with the apache error log

This page has some further information, such as the default location on windows of the logfiles

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html